# getting type 'text/plain' for png file, unpredictably

Tags: html, image, http, vue-cli-3

I'm using `new Image()` to preload some images,

my code:

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
  console.log('ok')
}
img.src = 'xxx'
```

but I notice that, sometimes the response type is 'png', and sometimes it is 'text/plain', why ?

[image]

[image]

My project is based on '@vue/cli' v3

I tried to create a minimal html demo, it gets 'png' type every time;

I tried to create a minimal 'create-react-app' demo, it also works fine;

Comment: maybe different servers?

Comment: I took a look at the 'remote address' on dev tool, the ip is the same @RolandStarke

Comment: mmm but maybe there is still some load balancing or if there is some cache in between the cache sends a different content type... but yeah.. no idea.